# Lagrange's interpolating polynomial

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials, na.numerical-analysis, approximation-algorithms, lipschitz-spaces

Let $f:[a,b]\rightarrow R$ be a function that is not $C^{(n+1)}$ on $[a,b]$ but its $n$-th derivative is a Lipschitz function? How does the Lagrange's interpolating polynomial formula change? How does the error approximation change? How can I use it in order to find Simpson's and Newton's formulas of quadrature? I have searched a lot but I could not find a proper demonstration in any numerical analysis book. Please help!

Comment: Why should the Lagrange formula change at all? It does not use the function, just its values in the nodes.

Comment: Have you tried examining what happens in low-degree cases such as $n=1$ or $n=0$?

Comment: @FedericoPoloni The usual remainder term is traditionally written with $f^{(n+1)}(\xi)$, which now is incorrect and should be replaced by $F$ where $F$ is some number between the $\sup$ and $\inf$ of the $n+1$-st derivative (existing a.e.) or just between $-L$ and $L$ where $L$ is the LIpschitz constant, if that is all that is known. The other changes are similar and the best way to see what should be done is *not* to search the literature, but *to go over proofs* and figure things out from the first principles. This advice applies to this situation and far beyond. Voting to close.

Comment: @fedja I agree with you that the remainder formula changes, I was just pointing out that the formula for the interpolating polynomial doesn't.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni I have no doubts that this was what you had in mind, but it was rather clear that it was not what the OP meant by "Lagrange formula" :lol:

Comment: Sorry for ambiguity guys. I just want to know what would be the error approximation if the n-th derivative is a Lipschitz function. I guess it could be |R(x)|<=L/(n+1)! * |u(x)|, where u(x)=(x-x1)(x-x2)...(x-xn) and L is the Lipschitz constant. Am i right?